# How to get new Python module random seeded instance per object

Tags: python-3.x, random

Hi I am creating genetic algorithm for solving snake game. I have `Game` class, it has implemented all snake game logic. I use it to evaluate every `Snake` in population.

I am generating random snacks for snake in game. But I need a way to generate the same random snacks positions for every new `Game` instance, so each snake in population will be evaluated in the same environment.

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self, width, height, phenotype, seed, game_representation_strategy,
             snake_length=5, snack_eaten_points=1, moved_toward_snack_points=0.1,
             moved_away_from_snack_points=-0.2):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.phenotype = phenotype
        self.seed = seed
        self.game_representation_strategy = game_representation_strategy
        self.snack_perspective = None
        self.snack_eaten_points = snack_eaten_points
        self.moved_toward_snack_points = moved_toward_snack_points
        self.moved_away_from_snack_points = moved_away_from_snack_points

        self.status = GameStatus.INITIALIZED
        self.snack = None
        self.snake = []
        self.score = 0
        self.direction = Direction.LEFT
        self.last_snack_distance = 0

        self.initialize_snake(snake_length)
        self.initialize_snack()
        self.initialize_last_snack_distance()
```

Comment: Can't you cache the positions?

Comment: I can but I think there is more elegant way ;-)

Comment: Yes, there is, I'll answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just

```py
from random import Random

rng = Random(your_seed_here)
```

And then call the normal functions from the `random` module on that instance.

```py
num = rng.randint(0, 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need or can supply a seed, and since these random numbers are pseudo-random numbers, you can replicate them by remembering your seed.

```
   seed = 0
   import random
   randNumberGenerator = random.Random(seed)
   number = randNumberGenerator.randint(0, 1)
   print(number)
```

Execute this script twice and you will get the same number.

Is that what you are asking for?

Comment: Yes the Random class is what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: @Jakub W: Great. Consider up-voting the solutions if you like them. :)